# UI validation in WiX custom action proceeds to server mode / installation

Tags: wix, wix4

Trying to verify user input in a custom dialog using wix4 (same behavior with rc2, rc3 and latest builds).

I found various examples of how it's supposed to work, but unfortunately I cannot get it right here.

There's a dialog to pick a folder, setting a property like this:

```xml
<Publish Dialog="CustomPropertiesDlg" Control="ChangeFooFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="FOO_DIR" Order="1" />
<Publish Dialog="CustomPropertiesDlg" Control="ChangeFooFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2" />
```

then I try to run validation when the user clicks Next:

```xml
<Publish Dialog="CustomPropertiesDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="UI_CheckFooDir" Order="1" />
<Publish Dialog="CustomPropertiesDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InvalidFooPathDlg" Order="2" Condition="FOO_DIR_VALID&lt;&gt;&quot;1&quot;" />
<Publish Dialog="CustomPropertiesDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="5" Condition="FOO_DIR_VALID=&quot;1&quot;" />

<Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomPropertiesDlg" Order="10" />
```

My expectation at this point is that an invalid directory will set `FOO_DIR_VALID`="0" (and "1" if it is).

It's trivial code like this:

```cs
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult VerifyFooPath(Session session)
{
  session["FOO_DIR_VALID"] = "0";
  var fooDir= session["FOO_DIR"];
  session.Log($"Checking whether {fooDir} contains a foo.exe file");
  if (Directory.Exists(fooDir) && File.Exists(Path.Combine(fooDir, "foo.exe")))
  {
    session.Log($"Foo directory accepted as {fooDir}");
    session["FOO_DIR_VALID"] = "1";
  }
  return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

Yet, even though the log shows me that the custom action executes and sets the `FOO_DIR_VALID` property and even though the UI shows me the "Nope, the path is invalid" dialog.. the installation proceeds straight to the server phase afterwards. If I close the dialog (a straight up copy of the default `InvalidDirDlg.wxs` with a different message) I want the UI to remain where it is. Let the user fix the error. Yet it skips the `VerifyReadyDlg` (the last screen) and immediately prompts for elevation. What am I doing wrong?

Log:

````
Action start 18:19:30: UI_CheckFooDir.
MSI (c) (F4:04) [18:19:30:414]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI5048.tmp, Entrypoint: VerifyFooPath
MSI (c) (F4:10) [18:19:30:415]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (F4:10) [18:19:30:415]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (F4:10) [18:19:30:415]: Connected to service for CA interface.
MSI (c) (F4!C0) [18:19:30:876]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding FOO_DIR_VALID property. Its value is '0'.
Action ended 18:19:30: UI_CheckFooDir. Return value 1.
Action 18:19:30: InvalidFooPathDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 18:19:32: WelcomeDlg. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (F4:34) [18:19:32:623]: Skipping action: MaintenanceWelcomeDlg (condition is false)
MSI (c) (F4:34) [18:19:32:623]: Doing action: ProgressDlg
MSI (c) (F4:34) [18:19:32:623]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 18:19:32: ProgressDlg. 
Action start 18:19:32: ProgressDlg.
Action 18:19:32: ProgressDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 18:19:32: ProgressDlg. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (F4:34) [18:19:32:729]: Doing action: ExecuteAction
MSI (c) (F4:34) [18:19:32:729]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 18:19:32: ExecuteAction. 
Action start 18:19:32: ExecuteAction.
MSI (c) (F4:34) [18:19:32:735]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (F4:34) [18:19:32:736]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (F4:34) [18:19:32:736]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (c) (F4:34) [18:19:32:736]: Switching to server: (snipped properties here)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `SpawnDialog` the `InvalidDirDlg`; `NewDialog` replaces the current dialog and `InvalidDirDlg` is designed as a popup. (It has only an OK button.)

Comment: Dear god. Thank you. This must have been a very dumb question, but that was wayy too subtle for me to see or notice. Appreciate the help.